# Python SQLite ToDo script

Tags: python, database, sqlite, function

I'm trying to make a script that asks the user to input a task, the task is then stored in a SQLite database. I am having a problem getting my delete function to work. Also when I input a new task I have to encapsulate in quotes in order to make it run.

```
import sqlite3
import sys 

con = sqlite3.connect('taskmgr.db')

def create_db():
    with con:
        c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ToDo")
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE ToDo(Id int, Task char20, Due char20)") 

def select_task():
    with con:
        cursor = con.execute("SELECT Id, Task, Due from ToDo")
        for row in cursor:
            print "Id:" ,row[0]
            print "Task:" ,row[1]
            print "Due:" ,row[2]

def insert_task():
    with con:
        print("New Task\n")
        Id = input("Enter Id: ")
        Task = input("Enter Task: ")
        Due = input("Enter Due Date: ")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO ToDo VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (Id, Task, Due))
        con.commit()

def delete_record():
    with con:
        print("Enter task Id to delete:")
        user = int(input())
        c.execute("DELETE FROM ToDo WHERE Id=?",(user))

c = con.cursor()        
create_db()

target= int(8)
while target != 9:
    target=int(input("\nGood Morning Curtis!\n \nSelect option:\n 1.New Task\n 2.Select Task\n 3.Delete Task\n 9.Quit\n\nUser: "))

    if target ==1:
        insert_task()

    elif target ==2:
        select_task()

    elif target ==3:
        delete_record()

    elif target ==9:
        print("good bye")
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? Does it not do anything silently?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the input requiring quotes, for Python 2 use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

The other problem is with the `execute` statement, specifically the values for the parameterised query needs to be of type tuple (or list), however, you are passing in an integer value. Try changing it to this:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM ToDo WHERE Id=?",(user,))
```

The reason is that wrapping a single value in parentheses does not create a tuple:

```
>>> for user in 1, (1), (1,):
...     print user, type(user)
... 
1 <type 'int'>
1 <type 'int'>
(1,) <type 'tuple'>
```

From the above you can see that `(1)` is still `1` and is of type int. Wrapping it in `()` did not convert it to a tuple. However, `(1,)` is a tuple. Alternatively you could pass a list of the parameters, e.g.

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM ToDo WHERE Id=?",[user])
```